# How to attach two models together using another model in rails project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Please I have been working on this project where I need to asssign some hostel attributes  to a specific user with a role. I created a hostel model as well as a user model using devise, rolify and cancan. I also created an assign model that has the hostel ID and user ID as its attributes. Below are my codes for better checking.

My hostel model

```
class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :assign_hostels

  attr_accessible :name, :location, :picture
  default_scope :order => 'id DESC'
end
```

User model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :assign_hostels

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :first_name, :lastname, :oname
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end
```

My assign_hostel model

```
class AssignHostel < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :hostel
  attr_accessible :user_id, :room_id
  validate :user_id, :uniqueness => true
end
```

In my hostel page, after i have created list of hostels. I created a assign hostel button which would open a new assign page to list all users with role of porter

```
<%= link_to 'Assign', accommodation_new_assign_hostel_path(:id => hostel.id) %>
```

New assign in controller

```
def new_assign_hostel
  @search = Search.new(:user, params[:search], :per_page => 2)
  @search.order = 'email'
  @users = @search.run
  @hostel = Hostel.find(params[:id])
  @porters = Role.find_by_name('porter').users
  @assign_hostel = AssignHostel.new(:hostel_id => params[:hostel_id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.js
  end
end
```

On my new assign page i created this

```
<% @porters.each do |porter| %>

  <%= porter.email %>

  <%= render 'assign_hostel_form' %>

<% end %>
```

The assign_hostel_form partial below

```
<%= form_for @assign_hostel, url: accommodation_create_assign_hostel_path(:hostel_id => @hostel.id) do |f| %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :hostel_id, value: @assign_hostel.hostel_id %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: @assign_hostel.user_id %>

  <%= f.submit "Assign" %>
<% end %>
```

But after clicking on the assign button, It seems not to pick any hostel or user id . Please how do I solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like a classic [`has_many :through`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) relationship:

[image]

Why not try this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :hostels, :class_name => 'Hostel', :through => :assign_hostels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assign_hostels, :class_name => 'AssignHostel'

  attr_accessible :email, :password, :first_name, :lastname, :oname
  rolify
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

end

class Hostel < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :users, :class_name => 'User', :through => :assign_hostels, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :assign_hostels, :class_name => 'AssignHostel'

  attr_accessible :name, :location, :picture
  default_scope :order => 'id DESC'
end
```

Comment: Thanks RICH. I did exactly has you described. When I created lists of hostel, I created an assign button in front of each hostels which links to a new assign page that lists all users that has a role of porter (devise and rolify). But I can't seem to find a way to assign this users to a hostel, even though i was able to pass the hostel ID to the new assign page. Please put me through. thanks

Comment: Okay, do you have a join table set up correctly for your has_many :through? If you're passing your hostel_id & user_id's to the form page correctly, you should be able to pass them through the controller. Is there any error which you could put up?

Comment: Thanks Rich, I have been able to successfully retrieve the hostel ID and user ID from the code you gave me. But is there a way I could display the name or email of the user ID i collected  when I display the user id on the assign hostel page. I can only see the id in number but i need it to display the email as well. Thanks

Comment: If you're using Devise, do you have a "name" column in your database? For email, you could create something like this in your show action @user = User.find(params[:id]), then you can reference @ user.email to output the email

Comment: Ok thanks. After assigning the hostel to a user. I displayed the assign table which displays the user_id and the hostel_id. Now I also want to display the user email that has the User_id I attached to the hostel. Can i get that from the controller like this @user= User.find(params[:id => assign_hostel.user_id])

Comment: From what you've written, you should be able to get it from the controller, but I believe your syntax for this code is incorrect: `@user= User.find(params[:id => assign_hostel.user_id])` -> @user= User.find(assign_hostel.user_id)

Comment: No problem - it might be wrong, but it will certainly help you out